# C# SQL Query to return records and related records

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table as follows

[image]

I have a query that runs each day to find anything that's 5 days old or greater and has a status of "In Progress" and set the status to "Declined".

What I need to be able to do is also set the status to "Declined" for anything with a Linked_ID (child) where the ID (Parent) has been changed.

So in the table I already set ID 1 to "Declined" but I also need to set ID's 2,3,4,8 and 10 to "Declined"

Below is what I have so far, any support would be amazing and really helpful

```
var Process = from a in db.Table1
              where a.Status == "In Progress" && a.Date_Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)
              select a;

foreach (Table1 a in Process)
{
 a.Status = "Declined";
}
```

Comment: You need a recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Declined declined = new Declined();
            declined.Query(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
        }
    }
    public class Declined
    {
        DataTable dt;
        public Declined()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date Created", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Link_ID", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 25) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Completed", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28) });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, "In Progress", new DateTime(2020, 9, 28),1 });

        }
        public void Query(DateTime date)
        {
            List<DataRow> rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.Field<string>("Status") == "In Progress") && (date.Date.Subtract(x.Field<DateTime>("Date Created")).Days > 5)).ToList();
            foreach(DataRow row in rows)
            {
                if (rows.Count > 0) ChangeChildren_Recursive(row, row.Field<DateTime>("Date Created"));
            }
        }
        public void ChangeChildren_Recursive(DataRow row, DateTime date)
        {
            int id = row.Field<int>("ID");
            DateTime rowDate = row.Field<DateTime>("Date Created").Date;
            string status = row.Field<string>("Status");
            if((status == "In Progress") && (date != rowDate)) row["Status"] = "Declined";

            List<DataRow> children = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.Field<int?>("Link_ID") == id) && (x.Field<int?>("Link_ID") != null)).ToList();
            foreach (DataRow childRow in children)
            {
                ChangeChildren_Recursive(childRow, date);
            }
        }
    }
}
```